# Targeting even rows of table through jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I want to give orange color to even rows through jQuery in table.

But that is not working for me.

Below is the html code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
         <title>
         </title>
         <meta charset="utf-8" />
         <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/custom.css" />
    </head>
    <body>
        <table class="myTable">
            <tr>
                <td>
                    one
                </td>
                <td>
                    two
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    three
                </td>
                <td>
                    four
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    five
                </td>
                <td>
                    six
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    seven
                </td>
                <td>
                    eight
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-3.1.1.min.js" ></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/custom.js" ></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Below is the code in `custom.css`:

```
table,table td{
    border: 1px solid white;
    background: green;
    color: white;

}
.highlight{
    background: orange;
}
```

Below is the code in `custom.js`:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.myTable tr:even').addClass('.highlight');
});
```

I am a beginner in jQuery.

I am looking for a short and simple way.

Comment: Remove the `.` from `addClass('.highlight')`.

Answer (score 3):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.myTable tr:even').addClass('highlight');
});
```

Remove dot from addClass function

Comment: It wont work `'.myTable tr:even'`! OP needs to style `td` elements!

Comment: Here I just made the correction to the code, and by using same logic you can put it on any of the eligible elements

Comment: So why did you copy his code and rewrite it in your answer? If you want to explain logic, you can use English. Also `:even` selector selects odd elements which is also not as per requirements.

Answer (score 2):

You are almost there. The problems in your code are

1. You want to highlight `td` and your selector is `tr`.
2. Syntax for `.addClass()` should be `addClass('highlight')` and not `addClass('.highlight')`.

Replace this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.myTable tr:even').addClass('.highlight');
});
```

with:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.myTable td:odd tr').addClass('highlight');
});
```

According to [documentation](https://api.jquery.com/odd-selector/) `:odd` selects even rows:

> In particular, note that the 0-based indexing means that, counter-intuitively, :odd selects the second element, fourth element, and so on within the matched set.

RUNNING CODE:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.myTable tr:odd td').addClass('highlight');
});
```

```css
table,table td{
    border: 1px solid white;
    background: green;
    color: white;

}
.highlight{
    background: orange;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="myTable">
            <tr>
                <td>
                    one
                </td>
                <td>
                    two
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    three
                </td>
                <td>
                    four
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    five
                </td>
                <td>
                    six
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    seven
                </td>
                <td>
                    eight
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
```

Comment: You are styling left side table only, where as I want rows of even number to be styled.

Comment: Why -1 please explain?

Comment: You solved for the case of odd even columns. OP wanted for alternate rows

Answer (score 2):

You dont really need jQuery to get this effect. Unless, you have a specific use case / requirement, you could just use the odd, even pseudo classes to accomplish your need.

Here is a sample.

```css
table,
table td {
  border: 1px solid white;
  background: green;
  color: white;
}
table tr:nth-child(even) td {
  background-color: orange;
}
.highlight {
  background: orange;
}
```

```html
<table class="myTable">
  <tr>
    <td>
      one
    </td>
    <td>
      two
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      three
    </td>
    <td>
      four
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      five
    </td>
    <td>
      six
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      seven
    </td>
    <td>
      eight
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Question says `Targeting even rows of table through jQuery`.

Answer (score 2):

This is a small example using CSS and jQuery :

```js
// Execute a function when the DOM is fully loaded.
$(document).ready(function () {

    // Set the .alt class for the alternate rows
    $('.myTable tr:nth-child(even)').addClass('alt');
});
```

```css
/** Style for the body **/
 body {
    font: 12px Tahoma, Arial, Helvetica, Sans-Serif;
}
/** Main class for the alternate rows **/
 .alt {
    background-color:#eee;
}
/** Style for the table **/
 .myTable {
    border-collapse:collapse;
    font-size: 0.917em;
    max-width:500px;
    min-width:450px;
}
.myTable td {
    border:1px solid #333;
    padding:4px 8px;
}
.myTable td:nth-child(1) {
    width:200px;
}
.myTable td:nth-child(2) {
    width:150px;
}
.myTable td:nth-child(3) {
    width:100px;
}
/** Style for the cointainer **/
 #body {
    clear: both;
    margin: 0 auto;
    max-width: 534px;
}
html, body {
    background-color:White;
}
hr {
    margin-bottom:40px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="body">
    
<h3>Table 1</h3>

    <table class="myTable">
        <tr>
            <td>As You Like It</td>
            <td>Comedy</td>
            <td>1600</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>All's Well that Ends Well</td>
            <td>Comedy</td>
            <td>1601</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Hamlet</td>
            <td>Tragedy</td>
            <td>1604</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Macbeth</td>
            <td>Tragedy</td>
            <td>1606</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Romeo and Juliet</td>
            <td>Tragedy</td>
            <td>1595</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    
<h3>Table 2</h3>

    <table class="myTable">
        <tr>
            <td>Hamlet</td>
            <td>Tragedy</td>
            <td>1604</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Macbeth</td>
            <td>Tragedy</td>
            <td>1606</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Romeo and Juliet</td>
            <td>Tragedy</td>
            <td>1595</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
```